# Incompatible pattern type when pattern matching a Class's generic parameter

Tags: scala, generics

Why does pattern matching on a Class's generic constructor parameter fail, while that on a method's generic parameter succeed?

I have a type class `Ev`:

```
sealed trait Ev[T]
case object EvInt extends Ev[Int]
case object EvStr extends Ev[String]
```

and a generic class like so:

```
class C[T](ev: Ev[T]) {
  val id: Int = ev match {
    case EvInt => 0
    case EvStr => 1
  }
}
```

The above pattern match on `ev` fails with:

```
error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : EvInt.type
 required: Ev[T]
    case EvInt => 0
```

whereas this works:

```
object C {
  def id[T](ev: Ev[T]): Int = {
    ev match {
      case EvInt => 0
      case EvStr => 1
    }
  }
}
```

For my purpose, I could work around this in various ways, e.g., by moving `id` into the `Ev` trait:

```
sealed trait Ev[T] {
  def id: Int
}

class C[T](ev: Ev[T]) { val id: Int = ev.id }
```

but I am curious why it fails.

Comment: Interesting! I can't tell you why this happened, but it seems to be fixed in Scala 3. Running your code on the latest version of Scala 3 works perfectly: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/IfdjqPagS3KoTCnULw61Og

Comment: GADTs support in **Scala 2** was not very good, **Scala 3** improved it a lot.

Comment: I can't tell why either (sounds like a question for someone with some good understanding of the compiler), but I can suggest another workaround: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/XliBHVAcQaqL4HBpflkuEg/4

Answer (score 2):

That makes sense to think that it should've worked in the first place. And as some people commented, scala 2 had some flaws in ADTs and type inference/checking.
And you already know the workarounds to this problem. So I'm just going to write **my "experiments"/assumptions** here.

The compiler says it requires an `Ev[T]`, but you're providing it with `EvInt` and `EvString`. But what I thought at first, was that it's trying to say under the hood that it requires `T`, but you're providing it with `Int` and `String`. And I thought why this is happening, is probably because of different rules to type inference in classes and methods and other identifiers. For instance, if you change your code to:

```scala
class C[T](ev: Ev[T]) {
  // or use ev.asInstanceOf[Ev[_]]
  val id: Int = (ev: Ev[_]) match {
    case EvInt => 0
    case EvStr => 1
  }
}
```

Everything would work fine! Because you're basically telling the compiler there is no concrete `T` here.

Note that you wouldn't face the issue if you specify the type:

```scala
ev match {
  case _: EvInt.type => 0
  case _: EvString.type => 1
}
```

Also, instead of case objects (which at first extend their own type), if you use `val`s, the **compilation error** would go away:

```scala
val eInt: Ev[Int] = EvInt
val eStr: Ev[String] = EvString

val id: Int = ev match {
  case eInt => 0
  case eStr => 1
}
```

So in general, I think the compiler couldn't prove the relation between `EvInt` and `EvString` with `Ev[*T*]`, and this problem of type inference was sort of common in scala 2. I'd say it's a bug, but I'm not confident about that.

Hope this helps!